# VB.NET Programmatically Create and Define Variables

Tags: vb.net

I'm looking to define string variables from an array of strings.

```
x(2) = {"bar","foo"}
```

How do I create variables out of bar and foo? And then how do I assign them a value?

Comment: Can you explain yourself more clearly?

Comment: I want to be able to create bar as a string (like you would Dim bar as String) and then assign bar a value, bar = "x"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use a [Dictionary](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/xfhwa508%28v=VS.100%29.aspx)(Of String,String)

```
 Dim x() As String = {"bar", "foo"}
 Dim dict As New Dictionary(Of String, String)
 For Each s In x
     dict.Add(s, "your value")
 Next
```

You can read/write the values very easy and fast:

```
dict("foo") = "another value"
```

The array-value is the key for the dictionary entry. Every key must be unique.

Comment: So Dictionary is just a more advanced 2D array, I might as well keep my data in a 2D string array...

Comment: It's easy to use and has faster read access via key. You don't need to iterate through the whole array to find it.

Answer (score 0):

Use a `Dictionary<string, object>`

Answer (score 0):

There is no such thing as the associate array in .net
Like what joel suggests, you can use a dictionary

```
//in c#:
Dictionary<string, string> myDictionary = new Dictionary<string, string>();
myDictionary.Add("bar", "x");
myDictionary.Add("foo", "fooValue");
string barValue = myDictionary["bar"];
```